# Getting Blank httpException message while trying to pass client certificate with dio

Tags: flutter, client-certificates, iis-10, dio, httpexception

I am getting blank httpException message while trying to submit client certificate by using Dio package.
`DioErrorType (DioErrorType.DEFAULT) :  HttpException (HttpException: , uri = [API_PATH])`

Same certificate is working when requesting with postman.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 05:56:55 GMT
```

Below is the code I am using

```
 Future<List<int>> loadCertificate(String assetPath) async {
    return (await rootBundle.load(assetPath)).buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

```
final List<int> certificateChainBytes =
        await loadCertificate('assets/certs/client-cert1.pfx');
    final List<int> keyBytes =
        await loadCertificate('assets/certs/client-cert1.pfx');
final Dio dio = Dio();
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
        (client) {
         final SecurityContext sc = SecurityContext()
                                  ..useCertificateChainBytes(certificateChainBytes, password: 'Secret')
                                    ..usePrivateKeyBytes(keyBytes, password: 'Secret');
      final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: sc);
     httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
            print('badcertificatecallback');
            print(cert.issuer);
            return true;
          };
          return httpClient;
        };
  try {
      url = url.contains('http') ? url : '${PsConfig.ps_app_url}$url';
      print('API Response from $url');
      final Response response =
          await dio.get(url, options: Options(headers: getHeaders()));

      return processHttpResponse(obj, response);
    } on diolib.DioError catch (e) {
      inspect(e);
      return processDioResponse(obj, e);
    } finally {
      dio.close();
    }
```

I am new to this and got stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to test application in visual studio? Did it work? If it still throw blank exception, you can set a break point at "catch" to debug what content of "e" is.

Comment: Yes I have tried to run application in VS. It works well if I set client certificate config to ignore. But throws httpException once I change that to allow or require.

Comment: Can you show the error page?